# How to show the amount of files in the sub-folders?

Tags: linux, ls, du

I have a folder named "A", and there are 3 sub-folders in it which are named "A1", "A2", "A3" respectively.

Is there a command to show the amount of files in each sub-folders?

E.g.

```
A1     5
A2     7
A3    18
```

Thanks.

Comment: Note: on Unix/BSD and Linux, too, they are directories. "Folders" is a Windows-ism for user directories and is not the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can loop over each subdirectory in `./A` and output the number of files/folders contained in each subdirectory with:

```
for i in A/*; do [ -d "$i" ] && echo "${i##*/}  $(ls -1 "$i" | wc -l)"; done
```

Which just loops over all files and folders in `A`, and if the current name is a directory, it echos the directory name and a count of the number of files/folders in that directory.

(**note:** that is a `ls -"one"` and a `wc -"ell"`)

To include hidden files in the subdirectories use `ls -a1` which is `-"a"one"` and then subtract `2` from each total (for `.` and `..`)

Give that a try and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: i don't see other solution then bits of shell script either. this one gets the job done

Comment: Somehow it didn't work for me. There are 3 files in A1/, 4 files in A2, 3 files in A3/, but it returns 5 for each folder.

Comment: bash-3.2$ for i in A/*; do [ -d "$i" ] && echo "${i##*/}  $(ls -1 | wc -l)"; done
And then it returns as follows:
A1         5
A2         5
A3         5

Comment: @JasonHuang -- good catch it should be `$(ls -1 "$i" | wc -l)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ls -R /path/to/A-diretory 

du -ah /path/to/A-direcory          //here it will tell the size of files too
```

*if you want to see your listing in tree like structure, use tree command, its a very powerful command having a lot of options.*

**before that**

```
apt-get install tree (for ubuntu)

tree /path/to/A-directory
```

You can always refer `man command` to explore more of a command